# VBA code to put blue borders around images in Word Doc

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, border

I have a word doc with PPT slide images in it. I need all the PPT images, but only the PPT images, to have blue borders around them. The slide images are 1.39 x 1.85, which is larger than all the little icon images, so I am trying to use that property to get only the slide images bordered. I can do it by hand, but each document has 70-90 slide images.

This is the code I tried:

```
Sub Borders()
Dim pic As Long, image As Long

With ActiveDocument.Range
For pic = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
    With .InlineShapes(pic)
    If .Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.39) Then
    .Borders(pic).Color = RGB(20, 86, 162)
    .Borders(pic).LineWidth = wdLineWidth1pt
    End If
End With
Next pic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I’m not seeing a question here. Is something not working, are there errors, or are you not getting the results you require? Use the edit link below your post to add details.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub Borders()
    Dim pic As Shape
    
    For Each pic In ThisDocument.Range.ShapeRange        'loop all shapes
        Debug.Print TypeName(pic)
        If pic.Height > CentimetersToPoints(1.39) Then   'check min size 
            With pic.Line                                'style the border
                .Visible = True
                .Style = msoLineSingle
                .Weight = 1
                .ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
            End With
        End If
    Next pic
End Sub
```